# resize images with canvas - css overflow issue

Tags: css, canvas, overflow

I'm working on a JavaScript image resizing feature which rely on the IE only DXImageTransform addon.

Wanting to address modern browsers as well, I gave a shot to canvas, with pretty good results.

However, I face an issue in my resize function, which is the following:

```
function Resize(oObj, flMultiplier)
{       
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');

  oObj.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  canvasContext.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // clear canvas
  canvasContext.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)';
  canvasContext.scale(flMultiplier,flMultiplier);
  canvasContext.drawImage(oObj, 0, 0);
}
```

If my image becomes bigger than the canvas item, then one will see only a portion of the image, which is bad.

I tried to tweak the canvas size at runtime, but if affects the display of the resized image.

So I ended up declaring a *big* canvas element, which is pretty OK, except that the css overflow of my web page is adjusted on my biggest element, and not on my resized image, which is a pain.

So I guess there are two ways to solve my problem:

1. Try to exclude the big canvas element from the overflow scheme
2. Try to update the canvas element size when resizing (I may have missed something there)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried that myself, but perhaps you can create a canvas element out of the Dom, with `document.createElement`. It could be of arbitrary size without disturbing the display.

Now, I lack context (why do you resize images this way instead of using width and height attributes, among other questions) so maybe I am missing the point.

Comment: Well, I had a hammer (used canvas so as to rotate images recently), so resizing looked furiously like a nail to me.
Anyway, I solved my issue using CSS resizing, it works perfectly.
Thanks fo the hint, I'll accept your answer for that.